# Chrome's cache not working, when refreshing

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, caching

In local development for a web app, I have a couple thousand JS files.

In order to not wait fifteen seconds on every refresh, I add cache headers to the responses

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public
```

On the page, I add cache breakers to the URLs that change if the file has changed.

```
<script src="file1.js?sha1=abc..."></script>
<script src="file2.js?sha1=def..."></script>
<script src="file3.js?sha1=123..."></script>
...
```

The doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox. No matter how I refresh my page ("hard", "soft"), the browser always makes a request for every single one of these thousand of files.

Is there a way to have Chrome and Firefox not ignore the cache for linked resources when refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers usually do a "304 Not Modified?" check on the files, or at least the ones that work correctly. Are you sure they're requesting and downloading each and every file? Or just making a check like that?

If there are thousands of files, I'd definitely consider combining and minify-ing them because that would mean your website would be slow to load each time.

Comment: Yes, they do 304 Not Modified...thousands of times. I don't minify in development because it makes them harder to read and takes time.

Comment: 304 Not Modified doesn't download the entire file unless it actually changed (hence the "Not Modified?" question) and will use the browser's cached copy. So double check that your cache breakers aren't changing all the time even if your file hasn't updated, because if you do see the file downloading every time, more than likely the issue is with the cache breaker. Otherwise the 304 is default behavior.